# Is it possible to extend the PBI View of TFS in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-workitem

I am using **Visual Studio 2012**, **TFS 2012**, and I want to do this for PBI (Product Backlog Items)

I would like to add a "button" or something of the sort to help me create Tasks for my PBIs. (This is something I have been requested to do).

So as I am Viewing a PBI or a List of PBIs I could have a button that popups a Window inside Visual Studio with some options which will trigger the creation of different tasks and such. Is this possible?

Or should I create a separate program that will allow me view the WorkItems and implement the functionality there (for example with C#/WPF)

Comment: Which TFS/Visual Studio versions are you using? Which process template? Exactly which work item? And, finally, yes, you can customize work items, even the work item forms, and can add custom controls.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I think we are using Scrum (I don't know how to check that yet), also, the only way is modifying the actual Template? Isn't there a way to do it at Visual Studio Level? If I modify the WorkItem template, that change is in the TFS server, no?

Comment: It sounds like you have been given the job of process template customization. You should read up on "[Extending Team Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146.aspx)".

Comment: @JohnSaunders, so just to be sure, you are saying that if I don't want to modify the WorkItem Template I need to use the "Extending Team Foundation"? Or "Extending Team Foundation" implies modifying the WorkItem Template?

Comment: You still haven't said which version of TFS you're using.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, sorry, didn't notice!

Answer (score 1):

You should look at following links. Looks like you are looking to create/update work items in bulk. You can easily import your pbi work items to excel and add/update in bulk or also use work item templates for that.

If that doesn't work then you can write code using TFS API to create work items and do other things as well. Using that you can have your own form and add custom steps and then call Api to create the work items.

TFS API to create work items:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3280.tfs-2010-api-create-workitems-bugs.aspx

Use work item templates to pre-populate fields: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407162.aspx

Bulk add or modify work items with Excel:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286627.aspx

Bulk modify work items:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409280.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This already exists out of the box.  When viewing a PBI go to the Tasks tab and click New.  It will create a new Task that is automatically linked back to the PBI.  It will also set the Iteration and Area to match the Parent PBI.

[image]

Comment: I know that functionality exists, I have to add some custom stuff in the middle, that is why I want to create my own button.

Comment: describe the custom stuff you want to add?

Comment: Request the person to input some information, send an email, etc. I need to put my own "form" in the middle, and then create the task (Actually will trigger the creation of several tasks not only 1)

Comment: You can set up alerts in TFS to automatically send emails to the person the task is assigned to.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I need other emails, but I just want to know if I can put a form in the middle, I know it is a bit far fetched, but is it possible?

Comment: It's not far-fetched, but that would mean writing a program or Visual Studio add-in, in which case also see the Visual Studio SDK. All of this is doable, but not trivial. As a separate program it's not too difficult. Try that first, then if that's not good enough for them, you can take the time to make it an add-in.

Comment: @JohnSaunders ah that is what I was looking for, so a separate program, or a Visual Studio Add-in? I will check that.

Comment: And then you can use TFS API to create the work items.

Comment: @Dzyann in TFS, you can create a custom control but that would mean, everybody who needs to use that button should have installed your setup including the custom control's dlls (this means every client needs to have a setup) but this way you can have your button in work item windows, not on visual studio.